# What indexes should be used when the query results are ordered by a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The question may be long but the problem is actually simple. I have 3 models: List, Appearance and Movie. A List has many Movies through an Appearance, and they should be sorted by the attribute rank of the joins model. So what indexes should I be using? This is how my models currently look:

```
# Models
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :appearances, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :lists, :through => :appearances
end

class Appearance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :movie
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appearances, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :movies, :through => :appearances

  def self.find_complete(id)
    List.includes({:appearances => :movie}).where("appearances.rank IS NOT NULL").order("appearances.rank ASC").find(id)
  end
end
```

And here are the indexes I already have. Do I need a composite index? Or just an index by rank?

```
# Tables
class CreateAppearances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :appearances do |t|
      t.integer :list_id, :null => false
      t.integer :movie_id, :null => false
      t.integer :rank
    end
    add_index :appearances, :list_id
    add_index :appearances, :movie_id
  end
end
```

Finally, is there any way to refactor that find_complete List method? Like using a default_scope? Don't forget that a rank may be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord is doing two queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `lists`.id
FROM `lists` LEFT OUTER JOIN `appearances` ON `appearances`.`list_id` = `lists`.`id`
             LEFT OUTER JOIN `movies` ON `movies`.`id` = `appearances`.`movie_id`
WHERE `lists`.`id` = 1 AND (appearances.rank IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY appearances.rank ASC LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT `lists`.`id` AS t0_r0, `lists`.`name` AS t0_r1, `lists`.`created_at` AS t0_r2, `lists`.`updated_at` AS t0_r3, `appearances`.`id` AS t1_r0, `appearances`.`list_id` AS t1_r1, `appearances`.`movie_id` AS t1_r2, `appearances`.`rank` AS t1_r3, `appearances`.`created_at` AS t1_r4, `appearances`.`updated_at` AS t1_r5, `movies`.`id` AS t2_r0, `movies`.`name` AS t2_r1, `movies`.`created_at` AS t2_r2, `movies`.`updated_at` AS t2_r3
FROM `lists` LEFT OUTER JOIN `appearances` ON `appearances`.`list_id` = `lists`.`id`
             LEFT OUTER JOIN `movies` ON `movies`.`id` = `appearances`.`movie_id`
WHERE `lists`.`id` = 1 AND `lists`.`id` IN (1) AND (appearances.rank IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY appearances.rank ASC
```

In both cases what you need is an index with both lists.id and appearances.rank.  Some databases will create indexes on multiple tables.  I also don't know if your database will be smart enough to use an index on appearances.list_id and appearances.rank, but that is worth a try.

```
add_index :appearances, [:list_id, :rank]
```

If that doesn't help, at least index :rank, so the database might be able to avoid the sort.

Comment: Indeed you are right that it is doing two queries. And I guess I should have explained in my question that I am using PostgreSQL. I'm going to try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at what queries Rails will output for your specific use-cases.

My best guess would be to add indexes on the foreign key columns and then **use a profiler** once the app is done and loaded with data to see if particular queries are performing poorly and fix them then!

Never try outsmarting your database, just measure and fix - anything else will most likely cost you more performance than it saves.

What you are asking here is in a form premature optimization and also a bit guesswork, considering how Rails3 Arel will defer execution so that what indexes are actually needed largely depends on how this association will be used and how it will be traversed.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your associations.
If

> *A List has many Movies through an Appearance*

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :appearances, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :movies, :through => :appearances
end

class Appearance < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :list, :foreign_key => list_id
 has_many :movies
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base  
 belongs_to :appearance, :foreign_key => appearance_id, :dependent => :destroy  
end
```

As for the find_complete method I don't see why turn it into a scope.Probably has to be done a bit shorter since you're already within the List model and looks very weird calling List.includes.... inside itself.

Don't see the need for that movie_id index

```
class CreateAppearances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :appearances do |t|
      t.integer :list_id, :null => false
      t.integer :movie_id, :null => false
      t.integer :rank
    end
  add_index :appearances, :list_id
 end
end
```

And also need an appearance_id index for your movies table.

I hope I'm not missing anything